# Is there a way to automatically resume after the breakpoint updates watch variables in Eclipse debugger?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

While I am debugging in eclipse, I have several variables I am watching, and place them in the variables or expressions windows.   The problem is, they are not being dynamically updated in real time, the program must be paused or breakpointed.   Is there any way to specify breakpoint actions, such that once the variables in the watch window have been updated, that the resume function can be automatic, instead of having to interact with the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

My associate gave me the answer, which others may find helpful:   All you have to do is right-click on the variable/expression and select `Enable Real-Time Refresh` from the drop-down list!